# Crash when deleting call and account with PJSUA/Swig on Android

Tags: android, swig, pjsip

I'm experiencing a crash with PJSUA (Swig) on Android when deleting a call and account in quick succession.

Here is the scenario from the Android application perspective:

1. Setup account and register with registrar
2. Receive inbound call (do not answer)
3. Receive disconnect event (caller hangs-up)
4. Delete call and account:

   ```
   call.delete();
   call = null;
   account.delete();
   account = null;
   ```
5. App crashes with:

> ```
> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x3a302063 (code=1), thread 28956 (com.sampleapp)
> *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
> Build fingerprint: 'google/nakasi/grouper:4.2.2/JDQ39/573038:user/release-keys'
> Revision: '0'
> pid: 28926, tid: 28956, name: com.sampleapp  >>> com.sampleapp <<<
> signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 3a302063
>     r0 3a302063  r1 00000007  r2 61f1c9a0  r3 3a302063
>     r4 00000001  r5 61ee805c  r6 61eea08c  r7 58cdf7c4
>     r8 68b5e360  r9 00100000  sl 58cdf7c4  fp 68e3ce84
>     ip 00000001  sp 68e3ce78  lr 689520b8  pc 68951bc8  cpsr 60000010
>     d0  000000000062e080  d1  3ff000004280cccd
>     d2  0000001c0000001b  d3  0001000100010001
>     d4  ff00550055005500  d5  00000131000f000f
>     d6  4034346dc5d63900  d7  0062e0808f5c28f6
>     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
>     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
>     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
>     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
>     d16 4158b82020000000  d17 3fe0000000000000
>     d18 0000000000000000  d19 002bf000002ad000
>     d20 0070c01d006c401c  d21 0079c01f0075401e
>     d22 0000000000000004  d23 0000002300000022
>     d24 0082c021007e4020  d25 008bc02300874022
>     d26 000000200000001f  d27 0000002200000021
>     d28 0070c000006c4000  d29 0079c00000754000
>     d30 0000000100000001  d31 0000000100000001
>     scr 80000090
>
> backtrace:
>     #00  pc 0008dbc8  /data/app-lib/com.sampleapp-2/libpjsua2.so (_JavaVM::DetachCurrentThread()+20)
>     #01  pc 0008e0b4  /data/app-lib/com.sampleapp-2/libpjsua2.so (Swig::Director::JNIEnvWrapper::~JNIEnvWrapper()+48)
>     #02  pc 00093fdc  /data/app-lib/com.sampleapp-2/libpjsua2.so (SwigDirector_Call::onCallState(pj::OnCallStateParam&)+384)
> ```

This is the easiest way to reproduce the problem but there are other scenarios where deleting the call and account causes the same crash.

I have debugged a lot and I believe the problem is that deleting the account while the call is closing causes the crash.

If I close only the call and later (2 seconds is enough) close the account, the crash does not happen.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to prevent this crash?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue ?

Comment: hi Isac, may I know why you are deleting your account just after delete your call. is this any standard rule. as I read till now, deleting account means like sign out.